# Настройка nginx+perl

Tags: nginx, perl, fastcgi

Решил себе поставить на ubuntu 14.04 nginx+perl+mysql. Поставил командой `sudo apt-get install mysql-server nginx fcgiwrap`. Установилось всё без проблем. Так же через cpan установил DBI и CGI, установка прошла успешно. Создал так же файл `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com` и в этот файл записал следующее:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name test.com;    access_log /home/www/test.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/www/test.com/logs/error.log;
    root   /home/www/test.com/public_html;
    location ~ \.pl$ {
        gzip off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.pl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/test.com/public_html/index.pl;
    }
    location / {
        index  index.pl;
    }
}
```

В директории `/etc/nginx/sites-enable` сделил символическую ссылку на `../sites-available/test.com`

Вот содержание файла /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.1.1   ubuntu 
127.0.0.1   test.com
```

Сам скрипт для запуска лежит по адресу `/home/www/test.com/public_html/index.pl` Вот его содержимое:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  #
  # The traditional first program.

  # Strict and warnings are recommended.
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  # Print a message.
  print "Hello, World!\n";
```

Перезапускаю nginx и переходя по адресу http://test.com/index.pl или просто по test.com получаю ошибку 502 BAD GATEWAY...

Вот что по этому поводу пишется в логе:

> 2017/03/27 05:13:35 [error] 2706#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: «Cannot execute script (/home/www/test.com/public_html/index.pl)» while reading response header from upstream client: 127.0.0.1, server: test.com, request: «GET /indexpl HTTP/1.1», upstream: «fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:», host: «test.com»

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться новичку с настройкой :)

Comment: А HTTP-заголовки из перла отдать?

Comment: @PinkTux каким именно образом? просто я новичек совсем, задание это делал по мануалу лабораторному... Буду весьма признателен за помощь или ссылку на годный ресурс)

Comment: Если это лабораторная, то правильней всего будет обратиться к материалам по пропущеным лекциям.

Comment: @PinkTux интересное мышление. есть проблема - не срабатывает скрипт, при том, что сам сервер отзывается нормально. вероятно где-то ошибка или в коде, или может даже в настройках перла, по не опытности мог что-то пропустить, но глаза разбегаются, по-этому и прошу помощи у "старших"... и да, на лекции я хожу, если что :)

Comment: Где проблема я уже сказал. Почитайте про основы работы CGI для начала.

Comment: @PinkTux Благодарю :)

Comment: добавьте `print "Content-type: text/html;\n\n";`  перед hello. и при желании какие нибудь еще заголовки. Правда в идеале печататься должна все таки HTML так что не помешали бы всякие там `<HTML><BODY>...`

Comment: @Mike отлично, спасибо, суть понял, всё заработало :)